# ¿Cómo puedo unir dos concultas sql para que me muestren lo que necesito?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 consultas que necesito unir para mostrar lo que requiero.
La primera es esta, que muestra el campo "is_hidden" en 1. Ese campo es importante, ya que indica si la propiedad está a la venta o no:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta otra consulta tengo un log que indica los motivos por los cuales las propiedades ya no están en venta. El valor "es_baja" 1 indica que ya no están en venta, al igual que el campo "is_hidden" de la otra tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta otra consulta trae las propiedades que ya no están en venta, pero si se repitieran los códigos de las propiedades (que en el negocio pasa) trae solo el último registro de la propiedad dada de baja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente, en esta otra consulta intento unir la primera consulta con la consulta de log que muestre solo el último registro de las propiedades dadas de baja:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, solo me trae los registros que tienen valores en la tabla de log, por lo tanto intento unir de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y resulta que ahora trae los valores de "is_hidden" en 1 y 0, y los campos de la tabla log vienen todos en null.

Adjunto el código de mi consulta:

```
SELECT  prop.cod_propiedad,                             mot.fecha,                          mot.es_baja,
        mot.motivo_cambio,                              tiprop.nombre_tipo_propiedad, 
        tipop.nombre_tipo_operacion,                    com.nombre_comuna,                  sec.nombre_sector,
        tipval.simbologia_tipo_valor,                   prop.valor_propiedad,               prop.observacion_propietario,
        cue.nombre_persona,                             prop.fecha_captacion_propiedad,     prop.cantidad_superficie_total_propiedad,
        prop.id_propiedad,                              prop.is_hidden 
FROM        propiedades prop
LEFT JOIN   tipo_propiedades tiprop     ON prop.id_tipo_propiedad = tiprop.id_tipo_propiedad
LEFT JOIN   tipo_operaciones tipop      ON prop.id_tipo_operacion = tipop.id_tipo_operacion
LEFT JOIN   comunas com                 ON prop.id_comuna = com.id_comuna
LEFT JOIN   sectores sec                ON prop.id_sector = sec.id_sector
LEFT JOIN   tipo_valores tipval         ON prop.id_tipo_valor = tipval.id_tipo_valor
LEFT JOIN   cuentas cue                 ON prop.id_cuenta = cue.id_cuenta
LEFT JOIN   motivo_cambio_estado mot    ON prop.cod_propiedad = mot.cod_propiedad
GROUP BY prop.cod_propiedad, 
         mot.motivo_cambio,                             tiprop.nombre_tipo_propiedad, 
         tipop.nombre_tipo_operacion,                   com.nombre_comuna,                  sec.nombre_sector,
         tipval.simbologia_tipo_valor,                  prop.valor_propiedad,               prop.observacion_propietario,
         cue.nombre_persona,                            prop.fecha_captacion_propiedad,     prop.cantidad_superficie_total_propiedad,
         prop.id_propiedad,                             prop.is_hidden,                     mot.es_baja
HAVING prop.is_hidden = 1 and mot.es_baja <> 0 and mot.fecha IN 
                                    (select max(fecha)
                                    from msanchez_bd.motivo_cambio_estado
                                    where es_baja <> 0
                                    group by cod_propiedad)
ORDER BY prop.id_propiedad  DESC;
```

Comment: Podrías colocar la estructura de tus tablas mejor, que las imágenes marean mucho.

Comment: Estas haciendo un left join con tu tabla log, por eso te une con todos sus log de vuelta, tienes que lograr primero unir con 1 solo registro del log, el que te interesa, que supongo es el ultimo, por lo tanto en vez de unirla con la tabla directamente puede ser una subquery que solo traiga el ultimo log de cada propiedad. 

Ademas, lo que tienes en el having son filtros individuales y no grupales, si los pasas al where la consulta se ejecutara bastante más rapido.